# Text is not showing or letter are being replaced with other letters

Tags: html, css, wordpress, text, visual-glitch

SOLUTION:
Remove font-family, font-size and color from the parent div.

EDIT: The problem occurs only when I press CTRL + F5

EDIT2: I tracked down the problem to .site-footer: position:absolute; .It seems that if I change it to relative the problem dissapears.

I'm getting a weird error on a website I'm currently developing.
There are 2 problems:

1. somethimes the text is not showing at all (though the border for the text is showing) but when I hover over it, it starts displaying.
2. The text is glitches Ex: instead of "SYDNEY" the text is "TZDOEZ" and I have to refresh the page or change the browser window dimensions to remove the problem.

Did someone else encountered the problem?

Just to be clear:

The text IS NOT the same color as the background.

The text is inserted by pure html not Javascript, PHP, etc

I use Open Sans font from Google Fonts.

It happens no matter what font I use.

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
<div class="full-width">
    <div class="left">
        <ul class="footer-list">
            <li><a href="#">Sydney</a> <span>Tel: +00 0 000 0000</span></li>                                              
           </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <ul class="footer-list">
            <li><a href="#">Sydney</a></li>                                             
           </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.site-footer {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
width: 100%;
background: #000000;
padding: 10px 20px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
font-size: 13px;
color: #bcbcbc;
}
.footer-list li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0 9px;
border-right: 1px solid #666666;
}
.footer-list a, .footer-list span {
display: block;
color: #ffffff;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;` and seeing if the bug persists?

Comment: Actually I tried adding it as an fix. It doesnt work with or without it.

Comment: EDIT2: I tracked down the problem to .site-footer: position:absolute; .It seems that if I change it to relative the problem dissapears.